# ClassCastException in Spring Cloud Contract MessageVerifier using ActiveMQ

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-contract

I've been playing around with Spring Cloud Contract all week.  I was able to get create a producer and consumer application using Spring Cloud Stream for the messaging.

I'm trying to rework the producer side to use ActiveMQ (with Virtual Topics).  I think I'm almost there.  I've written my own MessageVerifier and injected that into the base class of my test.  Now I'm getting:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.535 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.someconsumer.MessagingTest
>   validate_inviteContract(org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.someconsumer.MessagingTest)  Time elapsed: 0.802 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.ContractVerifierHelper.convert(ContractVerifierStreamAutoConfiguration.java:59)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:40)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.someconsumer.MessagingTest.validate_inviteContract(MessagingTest.java:27)

I can tell from the log files that the test message is being sent, and my custom MessageVerifier is picking the message up.  What step(s) am I missing?

If I define my MessageVerifier like so:

> public class ConsumerMessageVerifier implements MessageVerifier< ActiveMQTextMessage>

Then that resolves the ClassCastException, but leads to other problems an 'Application Failed to Start' error:

> Description:
>   Parameter 0 of method contractVerifierMessaging in org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier' that could not be found.
>           - Bean method 'contractVerifierMessageExchange' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate'
>           - Bean method 'contractVerifierMessageExchange' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.camel.Message'
>           - Bean method 'contractVerifierMessageExchange' in 'ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'consumerMessageVerifier'
>           - Bean method 'contractVerifierMessageExchange' in 'NoOpContractVerifierAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'consumerMessageVerifier'
>           - Bean method 'contractVerifierMessageExchange' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (stubrunner.stream.enabled=true) found different value in property 'stubrunner.stream.enabled'

So, I'm not sure if that's the right path or not.  So my questions are:

1. Should I be qualifying the MessageVerifier as above ?
2. If so what step(s) are required to resolve the 'Application Failed to Start' error?

Thanks!

Comment: From what I see you have also Stream on the classpath `ContractVerifierStreamAutoConfiguration`. Either remove Stream from the classpath (I assume that you don't need it), or disable it via a property `stubrunner.stream.enabled=false`

Comment: I disabled it.  Slightly different error but along the same lines: Parameter 0 of method contractVerifierMessaging in org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration.ContractVerifierIntegrationConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.MessageVerifier' that could not be found.

Comment: I can't seem to edit the original post, but the question is if my MessageVerifier should be qualified as MessageVerifier<ActiveMQTextMessage>, if if so what else is needed?  Do I need a custom ContractVerifierMessageExchange  ?

Comment: Yes, MessageVerifier needs to be typed. You also need `ContractVerifierMessaging` . You can check out the Spring Cloud Contract packages: `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp` , `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream`, `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.camel` or `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integration` for samples.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  If you want to phrase that as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MessageVerifier` needs to be typed. You also need `ContractVerifierMessaging` . You can check out the Spring Cloud Contract packages: `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.amqp` , `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream‌​`, `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.camel` or `org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.integr‌​ation` for samples.